# Attach Div to Image on mouse over

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using tiny MCE as editor. As you can see in image below from google blogger when ever you mouse over an image it shows up that div below image which is having "Small","Medium","Large" options .Any advice / samples how will I be able to do with JQuery ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare your div with links or any content and set its display css property to 'none'. Then you control it with jQuery like this.

```
var yourDiv = $("#ThatDiv");
$("#YourImage").hover(  
  function () {yourDiv.css('display','block');},
  function () {yourDiv.css('display','none');}
});
```

more on subject [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) (jQuery api). You might need to tweak the hover out function. (Like adding a timeout so it won't disappear instantly after mouseout.)

You can propably imagine html code that might look like this:

```
<img src="#" alt="" id="YourImage"/>
<div id="ThatDiv" style="display:none">
  <a href="">...ETC...
</div>
```

And you would also use css classes in external stylesheet instead of inline styles. But this is just an quick example.

Comment: What will happen if there are multiple images . Will this show the div exactly below image  as I dont see anything that says about its position.

Comment: You will have to get position of image (with jQuery) and then set absolute position to that div (again with jQuery). And also use class instead of id for your images.

Comment: It depends a lot on scenario.... but if your images will have dynamic size, then you should start with wrapper div, that has relative position. Put that images and div inside. Then at each image, you will have to count size of image and use its coordinates for positioning that div. Something like adding top position to value of image's height etc.